# Simple function onSubmit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to call a simple function onsubmit. I tried using onsubmit and also a listener with jQuery. My problem is that when the user presses enter he gets redirected to `mysite.com?`

```
<form id="teleport">
<input id="tInput" type="text" value="Type a location" />
<input type="button" id="tSubmit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>

$("#teleport").submit(function () {
teleport(document.getElementById('tInput').value);
});
```

How do I prevent anything from happening when submitting? Also .submit() is only detecting the enter key, how do I listen for both enter key and clicks on the submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the form. You can do that with `event.preventDefault()`:

```
$("#teleport").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    teleport(document.getElementById('tInput').value);
});
```

Alternatively, you could `return false` inside the `submit` event handler for the same effect.

The easiest way to make the button submit the form too will be to change it's type to `submit`:

`<input type="submit" id="tSubmit" value="Submit" />`

Or you could attach a `click` event handler to your current button and trigger the `submit` event of the form.

Answer (score 2):

Prevent submiting a form:

```
$("#teleport").submit(function (e) {
   teleport(document.getElementById('tInput').value);
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Submit event catches any way of submitting a form - both with clicking the submit button and enter key press.